# I want to open an ssh session in a script, then perform other commands locally, then send a command to the already opened ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to open an ssh session in a script, then perform other commands locally, then send a command to the already opened ssh session.

Specifically I want to run a shell script in Linux that 1st opens an ssh session in the background then continues and puts a database in read only mode, then run a command in the open ssh session, then puts the database back in write mode.
Every second counts when I am doing this and actually opening the ssh session takes about 80% of the time, so that is why I do not want to open the ssh session and send a command to it all while the database is in read-only mode.

I do not have access to `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

I think connection multiplexing is the answer for you.

The way it works is, if you have an existing `ssh` connection to the same server,
for example in another window on the same machine,
or a backgrounded session in your current login shell,
subsequent `ssh` connections to the same server can reuse the first,
significantly speeding up the startup time,
just like what you want to achieve.

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config` to enable it when connecting to your server:

```
Host yourserver
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
```

I use this everywhere, so instead of `yourserver` I use `*`.

Try this: `ssh` to the server in one window, after you're logged in, ssh to the same server in another window. This second connection will be must faster, as it doesn't need to authenticate and establish a connection, because it will be reusing the connection that already exists.